# Read webcam in python with multiprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, python-multiprocessing, video-capture

I have a simple program for reading webcams, but the reading results are very slow, so I lower the quality of reading images from the webcam, but the reading is still slow, so I try to use multiprocessing, so I'm testing a simple program to find out if my multiprocessing program is running correctly or not. but I don't know why the variable "cap" cannot be read. and I don't know how to solve it.

this is my program :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def get():
        global cap
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        return cap

def video(cap):
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        return frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = get)
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

        while True:

                frame = video(cap)

                cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == 27: #Key 'S'
                        break
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When you tried [this basic example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), you still get the same problems?

Comment: just now, the actual program that I made earlier relates to image operations, starting with reducing the size and quality of the image, then changing the perspective of the image, then detecting 3 colors with hsv, then determining the coordinates of the reading results, and then displaying the results of the program, but the results are too slow , then I got a suggestion from my friend to use multiprocessing in the image updating section of the webcam. so to make sure the multiprocessing program works, I started by making a simple program reading images with multiprocessing

Comment: thank you, that was is very helpful,

Answer (score -1):

Actually, cap has never been declared. Try to insert this line after your import satements:

```
cap = None
```

This will take care of the missing cap. Of course this will then lead to other problems in your code, but it is a stating point.

Good luck

Andreas